# Setup HTML5 mediaelement player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mediaelement.js

I am very new in HTML5 player and need help. I am using the latest mediaelement.js file for the player. I am facing problem in certain cases. I have initialized the player and now want to do some work around :

- Initially initialize the HTML5 mediaelement player and load all the controls but not pass the video src
- Pass the video src once the live url coming wowza server is available as `player.setSrc('url')`
- Change the video url onclick and the player to restart the video playing for the new src
- How to define the `provider` and `netconnectionurl` in the player as we can define in flowplayer
- Loading of player is not smooth in android tablet and also sometimes browser crashes on  fullscreen

I tried to load the player initially without passing the video src but it does not load the controls only shows **Download File**. This is important for me as the live url comes after a delay from the server and i need to initailize the player before. Changing video url onclick seems to work for browser that supports HTML5 but in browser that uses flash fallback the video src does not change onclick. I have different channels and i want to load the channel url and play the video onclick. I don't want to pass the `rtmp` url with the stream url. I want to define it in the player from before and if possible change it dynamically. In android dont know why sometimes player does not load properly and browser crashes. Any help would be great.